# record a video and post to server then streaming it, always get AVPlayerItemTimeJumpedNotification and then AVPlayerItemPlaybackStalledNotification

Tags: ios, avfoundation

I am using AVFoundation to record a video and then upload to a server, and use AVPlayer to streaming it to play, but always get these 2 error notifications, is there any thing wrong in my output settings

```
NSDictionary *settings = @{AVVideoCodecKey : AVVideoCodecH264,
                               AVVideoWidthKey : @(480),
                               AVVideoHeightKey : @(480),
                               AVVideoScalingModeKey : AVVideoScalingModeResizeAspectFill,
                               AVVideoCompressionPropertiesKey:@{
                                       AVVideoAverageBitRateKey : @(480*480*11.4),
                                       AVVideoMaxKeyFrameIntervalKey : @(24)
                                       }
                               };
```

But I can play it very well with AVPlayer locally (means in iPhone)

Comment: Please check your code and `AVPlayerItem` properties and also check some samples [Ref Link1](https://github.com/iMoreApps/AVPlayer-for-iOS-Demo)[Ref Link2](http://docs.xamarin.com/recipes/ios/media/video_and_photos/play_a_video_using_avplayer/)[Ref Link3](http://iosdeveloperzone.com/2012/10/01/tutorial-playing-audio-with-avaudioplayer/)

Comment: @iOSFreak thanks, but my AVPlayerItem code should be fine, because I can play it locally.

Comment: please check Apple's code as well [Link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/AVPlayerDemo/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010101)